Have pandas autodetect Spyder console width
I am on Spyder 5.4.3 and Python 3.9, both installed via Anaconda on a Windows 10 machine.  The console width changes a lot depending on whether view only the console window (Shift+Ctrl+Alt+M), whether I've snapped the Spyder app to one edge/corner of the Windows desktop, and other resizings that I might have done.
I am following this Q&A to try and have pandas autodetect my Spyder console width, but it still doesn't make use of the full width.  What am I doing wrong?
import pandas as pd

# Truncated even though console has much more width
#---------------------------------------------------
>>> pd.set_option('display.width',None)
>>> pd.get_option('display.max_columns') # 0
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
       'A':['AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA','AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'],
       'B':['BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB','BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB'],
       'C':['CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC','CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC'],
       'D':['DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD','DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD'],
       'E':['EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE','EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE']})
>>> df
                     A                  B  ...                  D                  E
  0  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  ...  DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD  EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
  1  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  ...  DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD  EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
  [2 rows x 5 columns]

# Wraps around even though console has much more width
#------------------------------------------------------
>>> pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
>>> df
                     A                  B                  C                  D  \
  0  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC  DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
  1  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC  DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

                     E
  0  EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
  1  EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

I debated writing a function to set the pandas terminal width based on os.get_terminal_size(), but it has the wrong number of columns (80, much fewer than in reality).  Besides, even if I put such a function in my Spyder startup file, removing all variables also deletes the function.
